# Keeping iPod idle and still be able to contact server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipod

When I run my application on iPod touch, I keep my device idle and but programatically, every 30 seconds I make a server call and do some activity (like playing sound).

Now, after some time device sleeps and my application stops contacting server. I want to keep the device active as long as it is talking to server no matter whether a user is interacting with it or not.

How can this be achieved

Comment: In other words, you want to kill the user's battery.

Comment: If this is the requirement need. I guess I can keep the setting of never auto-locking. This should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Stops the screen dimming when your application is running and is in the foreground.